# Purification of isoborneol

Tags: organic-chemistry, purification

How can I convert isoborneol powder to isoborneol flakes?

I have made the isoborneol powder from reduction of camphor using sodium borohydride.

Comment: Recrystallisation ?

Answer (score 2):

*iso*-Borneol is a fairly common reagent, and methods for its preparation and purification are readily accessible (even without journal access). For information, the entry in *Purification of Laboratory Chemicals* suggests recrystallising from ethanol or petroleum ether, melting point data is also provided as a way of assaying the resulting material  (though NMR would be better).

> ***dl*-Isoborneol** *[124-76-5]* **M 154.3, m 212° (sealed tube).** Crystallise isoborneol from EtOH or petroleum ether (b 60-80°). It sublimes in a vacuum. The *4-nitrobenzoyl* derivative has **m** 153°. [Yager and Morgan *J Am Chem Soc* **57** 2081 1935, *Beilstein* **6** II 80, **6** III 299, **6** IV 281.]
>
> <sup>Taken from *Purification of Laboratory Chemicals*, 7 ed. Armagero and Perrin</sup>

Its worth noting that a *powder* and *flakes* are essentially just two amorphous forms, and there isn't really any benefit of having one over the other (if anything, the powder is more convenient to handle).